# Delete option of a Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

[image]

I am getting below error while I click on `Delete` word under name of a plugin.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wordpress will popup for FTP credentials if it does not have permission to write the files it needs to. Am assuming your WordPress website is hosted on Linux OS. And also if you connected to your server using SSH (i.e., putty, etc.). Please try to run the below command:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
```

**Alternate Method:** Try to define below the line in wp-config.php. But this could create security issues.

```
define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');
```

Comment: it should not necessarily be on an ubuntu machine.

Comment: @vishwa that's why I mentioned am assuming :)

Comment: you should say that you're assuming it runs linux os.. works for anything :), plus what if OP runs apache instead of nginx? then he should go look for different directory in different path. anyway +1 for the answer

Comment: @Vishwa I edited my answer